# How to enumerate through an anonymously-typed collection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, anonymous-types

This is what I have:

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person { Name="test", Age=1 },
    new Person { Name="tester", Age=2 }
};

var items = list.Select(x =>
{
    return new
    {
        Name = x.Name
    };
});

foreach (object o in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(o, null));
}
```

I feel like I'm not doing it correctly.

Is there a simpler way to access properties of anonymous types in a collection?

Answer (score 18):

Use the `var` keyword in the `foreach` line as well, instead of the general `object` type. The compiler will then automatically resolve the anonymous type and all its members, so you can access the properties directly by name.

```
foreach (var o in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o.Name);
}
```

Comment: +1.  Handling Anonymous types is the reason the `var` keyword was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = list.Select(x =>new { Name = x.Name });
        foreach (var o in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.Name);
        }
```

Just use var and you'll have complete type support

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this?

```
var items = list.Select(x => x.Name);

foreach (var o in items)
    Console.WriteLine(o);
```

You're only getting a single field, no need to create another anonymous type.

Comment: Or even `list.Select(x => x.Name).ForEach(o => Console.WriteLine(o));`

Comment: @BoltClock: let's not get so extreme :).

Comment: You have a point, though. If the OP only wants to print the names of each person and nothing else...

Comment: @BoltClock: at first glance, I'd say that's what he wants. That's why I simplified things that much.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are sufficient enough.
Just about simplification, notice than you didn't reacj the maximal simplification possible.
You can write

```
list.ForEach(person => Console.WriteLine(person.Name));
```

or

```
list.Select(person => person.Name).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to iterate through the whole anonymous collection anyway, you could `ToList()` it and use the `List.ForEach()` method:

```
   List<Person> list = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person { Name="test", Age=1},
        new Person { Name="tester", Age=2}
    };

   var items = list.Select(x =>
        {
            return new
            {
                Name = x.Name
            };

        }).ToList();

   items.ForEach(o => Console.WriteLine(o.Name));
```

Comment: @Dani: Just tried it without the ToList and I get: Error 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)